# Layout is scaling my JList's

Tags: java, swing, jlist, gridbaglayout, springlayout

I am using the [DualListBox.java](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/DualListBoxSample.htm) example but the issue I have is that the width of the JList scales based on the length of the entry. Ideally I want the `left JList` to take up 40% of the width, the `JButtons` to take up 10% and the `right JList` to take up the remaining 40%.

```
private void initScreen()
{
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    title = new JTextField("");
    title.setEditable(false);
    add(title, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
            EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));

    sourceLabel = new JLabel(DEFAULT_SOURCE_CHOICE_LABEL);
    sourceListModel = new SortedListModel();

    sourceList = new JList(sourceListModel);
    sourceList.addListSelectionListener(new AddSelectionListener());
    add(sourceLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
            EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));
    add(new JScrollPane(sourceList), new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 5, .5, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
            GridBagConstraints.BOTH, EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));

    addButton = new JButton(ADD_BUTTON_LABEL);
    add(addButton, new GridBagConstraints(1, 3, 1, 2, 0, .25, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
            EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));
    addButton.addActionListener(new AddListener());
    removeButton = new JButton(REMOVE_BUTTON_LABEL);
    add(removeButton, new GridBagConstraints(1, 5, 1, 2, 0, .25, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
            new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5), 0, 0));
    removeButton.addActionListener(new RemoveListener());

    destLabel = new JLabel(DEFAULT_DEST_CHOICE_LABEL);
    destListModel = new SortedListModel();

    destList = new JList(destListModel);
    destList.addListSelectionListener(new RemoveSelectionListener());
    add(destLabel, new GridBagConstraints(2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
            EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));
    add(new JScrollPane(destList), new GridBagConstraints(2, 2, 1, 5, .5, 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
            GridBagConstraints.BOTH, EMPTY_INSETS, 0, 0));
}
```

The `DualListBBox()` is added to a JPanel which is is added to a [compact grid](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringGridProject/src/layout/SpringUtilities.java)

```
SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(content, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6);
```

I don't have if the panels have horizontal scrolling, i just want them both to be the same width. Can anyone more familiar with grids and layouts give me some pointers or do you see anything wrong in the above code for values?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the `weightx` values be more like `0.4`/`0.1`/`0.4` (and you probably want the lists to fill both horiztonally and vertically

Comment: @MadProgrammer The weights are okay, it was the the Spring Utilities used to make the grind. Instead of it, i created a panel with a BorderLayout.CENTER and problem solved :) Layouts confuse me haha.